# In JavaScript is there a way to defer the processing of web socket messages until a flag is set?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, concurrency, websocket, stomp

Background:  I have a server that holds state for a grid of data.  The grid is continually being updated - e.g. new rows, updated rows, deleted rows.  I need to display this on a web page and reflect updates as they occur.

When the web page initially loads, I make an ajax call to retrieve the initial snapshot of data at that point in time.  I'm using Web Sockets (Stomp) to receive events for any changes that occur to the grid of data.

To ensure the correctness of the data that is shown in the browser, I need to subscribe to the event messages before obtaining the initial load of data, followed by applying those events. This ensures that no events are lost and that the client state is in sync with the server state.

I therefore need a mechanism which allows the processing of incoming events to be deferred until the processing of the initial load of data is completed.

Note that the update messages being sent over Stomp are on a generic topic that all clients subscribe to.  There is no client session state being maintained on the server side.

EDIT: I did think about using a queue based approach.  However I think there are still some concurrency concerns with the approach.  Based on the sample code shown below by @jfriend00: Once the initial data processing is done and the processQueue() function is called, you could still be getting events coming in.  In this case you would want to keep appending these onto the queue.  Its only at the point that the queue is empty that you would want to switch the incoming events to being processed directly by the processWsData() function.  Although I'm not entirely sure how you could solve the concurrency issue that exists here of setting a flag to say that initial data processing is done and ensuring that items don't get put onto the queue after that flag has been set. You essentially need some synchronisation against the flag.

Comment: Maybe you can send the client a 'state':'ready' message once everything is set up and on the client site ignore any message received prior to the 'state':'ready'?

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon how some things you have not described work.  If you set up your websocket listener first and then go do your initial data grab (like you were contemplating), then you just need to defer the processing of incoming messages until the initial data is done being processed.  You can do that by setting up a queue for any incoming messages that arrive while you're doing the initial data grab and and then process the queued messages when the initial data is done.

You don't show any of your code (which always makes it harder to provide the best answer), so I'll make up some code to show you the concept:

```
var initalizeDone = false;
var initialQueue = [];

function processWsData(data) {
    // implement code here to process a webSocket message
}

function processQueue() {
    for (var i = 0; i < initialQueue.length; i++) {
        processWsData(initialQueue[i]);
    }
}

// websocket data handler
ws.onmessage = function(event) {
    if (initializeDone) {
        initialQueue.push(event.data);
    } else {
        processWsData(event.data);
    }
}
```

Then in whatever code that does your initial processing, when it is done processing that data, it will just do this in order to catch up on any data that was queued while it was processing:

```
processQueue();
initalizeDone = true;
```

---

If your code cannot handle the possibility of a duplicate event, something that came in both the initial grab of data and in the webSocket, then you will have to fix that in whatever way is most appropriate to your data.  One technique that makes solving problems like this simpler is to assign a monotomically increasing number to each piece of data that is sent from the server.  Then, you can record what the highest id is for any piece of data you got in the initial data grab and skip any websocket messages that are not higher than that.

There are, of course, all sorts of data-specific methods of determining whether you've already processed a given piece of data or not, but those all depend upon the specific data.

Comment: Thanks for putting together a code sample.  Please see my edit to the question.